# NDVI value calculation and Image Processing

Tags: python, opencv, crop

[image: we have attached our input and processed image[![][1]][1]]I am an engineering student working on a project based on NDVI calculation to monitor crop health. I used the PiNoIR camera with a blue filter for my experiment in order to obtain the values of the NIR and the [Red Region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWLrP.jpg). I used the following code to extract the required values and to calculate the NDVI. But in the output image, the empty regions (the area where no leaves are present as shown in the below figure) and ground have higher NDVI values. The shadowed regions are shown in the range from `0.5` to `0.6`. I wanted to know whether the output is correct and what corrections can be done in the -code in order to correct the error. The code is given below.

```
from PIL import Image

import numpy as np
import cv2
from cv2 import imread
from matplotlib import cm
rgb_matrix =cv2.imread('inputimg.jpg')
w=rgb_matrix.shape[1]    #columns
h=rgb_matrix.shape[0]    #rows
print(w)
print(h)
#Compute ndvi values for each pixel
#NDVI=(NIR-R)/(NIR+R)
res=[]
for i in range(h):
 row=[]
 for j in range(w):
 val=rgb_matrix[i][j]
n=val[2]
 r=val[1]
 num=((int(n)-int(r)))   
 den=((int(n)+int(r)))
if(den == 0):
 r=0.0    
 else:
  r=np.divide(num,den)
  row.append(r)
    res.append(row)
print('Done')
#based on NDVI values, give different colors for easier identification
for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):
        if(res[i][j] >=-1 and res[i][j] <0):
            rgb_matrix[i][j]=[128,128,128]   #grey
        elif(res[i][j]>=0 and res[i][j]<0.2):
            rgb_matrix[i][j]=[64,255,0]    #parrot green
        elif(res[i][j]>=0.2 and res[i][j]<0.3):
            rgb_matrix[i][j]=[125,255,255]    #yellow
        elif(res[i][j]>=0.3 and res[i][j]<0.4):
            rgb_matrix[i][j]=[0,128,128]   #dark green
        elif(res[i][j]>=0.4 and res[i][j]<0.5):
            rgb_matrix[i][j]=[255,255,0]     #sky blue
        elif(res[i][j]>=0.5 and res[i][j]<0.6):
            rgb_matrix[i][j]=[255,51,153]    #purple
        elif(res[i][j]>=0.6 and res[i][j]<0.7):
            rgb_matrix[i][j]=[0,128,255]    #orange
        elif(res[i][j]>=0.7 and res[i][j]<0.8):
            rgb_matrix[i][j]=[255,43,255]   #pink
        elif(res[i][j]>=0.8 and res[i][j]<0.9):
            rgb_matrix[i][j]=[40,40,255]      #red
        else:
            rgb_matrix[i][j]=[255,0,0]       #dark blue
cv2.imwrite('outputimg.jpg',rgb_matrix)        
print("Completed!!")   
(Ignore the induntation errors)
```

Comment: Without having the original image its hard to say. But are you 110% sure that you're correctly grabbing the NIR and Red bands? The inversion problem sounds like an issue with which bands are getting used.

Comment: Kindly include your image, or a link to it. Thank you.

Comment: @Nebulous29 We got the concept of the shifting from the below-mentioned link. According to that, using the filter will generate the image in (NIR, R, G) image instead of(R, G, B). Link: publiclab.org/wiki/ndvi

Answer (score 1):

A few things... firstly, be aware that OpenCV uses BGR ordering not RGB like your code seems to assume. That likely means that you have selected the wrong channels as Red and NearIR - if so my code will have the same error.

Secondly, you really, really want to try and avoid doing image processing in Python with `for` loops - they are seriously slow, hard to read and prone to errors of loop limits. The following is untested code as you have not supplied an image, but it should give you an idea:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load image and convert to float - for later division
im = cv2.imread('inputimg.jpg').astype(np.float)

# Split into 3 channels, discarding the first and saving the second as R, third as NearIR
_, R, NearIR = cv2.split(im)

# Compute NDVI values for each pixel
NDVI = (NearIR - R) / (NearIR + R + 0.001)
```

That takes us up to where you print `Done` in your code. Note that, if you were unaware that OpenCV uses BGR ordering, the 1st and 3rd channel will need swapping, i.e.:

```
NearIR, R, _ = cv2.split(im)
```

The next part is assigning a colour which I'll leave you to think about  - bear on mind that your NDVI will be a float in the range [-1,1], so you may want to multiply it by 10 and convert to integer to assign one of your 9 colours...

Kindly upload an image so folks can answer you better.

Comment: We have attached our input image can you go through that and help us in solving this problem

Comment: We got the concept of the shifting from the below-mentioned link. According to that, using the filter will generate the image in (NIR, R, G) image instead of(R, G, B).
Link: https://publiclab.org/wiki/ndvi

Comment: I'm trying to implement NDVI, stuck on the same issue, have you been able to find a workaround?

Comment: @Akriti I'm normally able to give my best answers when people ask 1) well-posed questions, 2) with image data, 3) that they understand what it represents and 4) are responsive when I ask for clarification of details.